I am trying to edit a function for a scatterplot I have made in python
How would I go about editing the legend to have just the 80, 160, 240,... output shown in the pictures below?
Top is mine and bottom is expected.
The code I have that sets the plot is listed below. Thanks
sns.relplot (
    x='Average_Temperature_Celsius', 
    y='Average_Precipitation_mm', 
    hue='City_Name', 
    size='Elevation_Meters', 
    data=finalData, 
    palette='colorblind', 
    legend='full'
)

Top-Mine
Bottom-Expected

Don't put the question blindly. As a newcomer first trying to resolve some issue and then put your question ....

I have spent a fair amount of time searching this syntax. Can't seem to find it
